# Laravel withOnly not restricting the query

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following `User::class`:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /* ........ */

    protected $with = ['subscription', 'photo'];

    public function subscription(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Subscriptions::class, 'id', 'subscription_id');
    }
    
 
    public function photo(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Files::class, 'id', 'photo_file_id');
    }
}
```

By using the `$with` the relationships `subscription` & `photo` are always loaded when querying the `User::class`.

However, sometimes I'd like to avoid the relationships. [The documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-by-default) says:

> If you would like to override all items within the $with property for
> a single query, you may use the withOnly method:

So with that in mind, I performed the following query:

```
$notifications = \App\Models\Notifications::withOnly('fromuser')
    ->where('to_user_id', auth()->user()->id)
    ->limit(15)
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

Yet the Laravel Debug Bar shows that both `subscription` and `photo` relationships were loaded. Also if I output `$notifications->toArray()` the relationships are shown as well.

The `Notifications::class` is pretty straight forward:

```
class Notifications extends Model
{
    /* ..... */
    
    public function fromuser(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'from_user_id');
    }

    public function touser(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'to_user_id');
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

---

**Edit**: I know I can do:

```
\App\Models\Notifications::with(['fromuser' => function($query)
{
    $query->without(['subscription', 'photo']);
}])
```

But I was looking to avoid this because:

1. I call `User::class` is hundreds of places
2. I might add more relationships later

If it's not possible to just do `->withOnly` I might just forget about using `$with` property.

Comment: Seems like you are applying withOnly to the Notification not the User class.

Comment: Indeed, but there doesn't seem to have any other option apart from using `without` along with `withOnly`.

Comment: Did you try to use withOnly inside of public function fromuser() on the User class?

Comment: I did not, but that would throw out the purpose, because if I'd like to have all relationships of `fromuser` in another controller, it wouldn't work (?).

Comment: True. The only option I see right now is to have two distinct functions for fromuser, one with the complete user object being returned, one with the limited one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't have that much of choices:
You can create a scope inside your Notification

```php
class Notifications extends Model
{

    public function scopeWithUser($query, $relations = [])
    {
        return $query->with(['fromuser' => fn($query) => 
            empty($relations)
                ? $query->setEagerLoads([])
                : $query->withOnly($relations)
        ]);
    }
}
```

Then:

```php
Notifications::withUser()->get()
```

Or if you have other relation to eager:

```php
Notifications::withUser()->with('relation1')->get()
```

So it's up to you how to organize an modify the code to suit your needs

**Update:**

If I can recall, The `$with` it depends always on model columns, so if you don't select for exmaple `subscription_id` and `photo_file_id`, the relations won't be loaded automatically !

Would you give it a try

```php
Notifications::with('fromuser:id,name,email')->get()
```

Comment: That seems too much of a work, but I get your logic. I think that for now I'm just gonna use a middleware that loads for the current user all the relationships and thats it. I don't need to change anything else.

Comment: @Linesofcode, I did update my solution, hope it works for you !

Comment: I'm gonna accept your answer because it solves the problem, however, I'm not gonna use your solution because, again, it's too much work to select all the time only the necessary fields and avoid the relationships. I posted as an example 2 relationships, but I'm currently with 5. Thanks !

Comment: @Linesofcode, I feel you. For me I don't use $with , to avoid that extra scénarios. (Cons more that Pros in big projet and many nested relations). Good Luck!